# How can I use a content source field in tumblr custom HTML theme?

Tags: templates, themes, tumblr

I'm trying to create a custom HTML theme in tumblr.com I'd like to use a content source field which is highlighted on image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/5xkM5.jpg

For example I want to place a custom discription below a post:

```
>  Original post you can see <a
> href="$content_source_field">hire
```

Please help me with code for my theme.

Answer (score 0):

The variable that use "$content_source_field" is something that tumblr will automatically determine, you don't need to set it to anything specific.

In order for tumblr to know which URL to use (either the content source or the post entry), you'll need to use {LinkURL} as the href value.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`{block:ContentSource}`](http://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes/#content-sources) variable for this. If you define it, tumblr won't override it. Dont forget to add a `{block:RebloggedFrom}` variable too; otherwise tumblr will add the *via {some resource}* automatically:

```
{block:ContentSource}
    Original post you can see <a href="{SourceURL}">here</a>
    via {block:RebloggedFrom}<a href="{ReblogParentURL}">{ReblogParentTitle}</a>{/block:RebloggedFrom}
{/block:ContentSource}
```